# What's the smartest way to typeset a poem which includes prose?

Tags: environments, verse

I have a script to query a database containing poems and typeset them in `LaTeX` within a `verse` environment. Some poems contain section which are in prose. These prose lines are clearly tagged in the database (`<prose> ... </prose>`) so I am able to manipulate them.

I am then exploring how to typeset them smartly in `LaTeX` (maybe defining a specific *in verse* "sub" environment?).

The results should be that

1. The numeration of poem lines stops at the prose line to then
   continue immediately after;
2. I should be able to define the styling of *in
   verse* prose globally for the whole document as I do with the verse
   environment.

Please consider the following MWE, with the `verse` environment as typeset by my script.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}

\verselinenumbersleft
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-2em}
\poemlines{1}

\begin{verse}
To see a World in a Grain of Sand\\
And a Heaven in a Wild Flower,\\!
<prose>AND here some prose, which shouldn't be enumerated and also should be styled differently</prose>\\!
Hold Infinity in the palm of your hand\\
And Eternity in an hour.\\!
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: May be end `verse`, add the prose, restart `verse` and set the counter correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an environment `insideverse`, as you proposed yourself, disable the line number inside, store the line counter number and store it back after the prose part ended. The style of the prose part can be changed in the `begin` command section of the environment. The outer formatting is not affected, since all is safe in a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{saveverselinecounter}

\newenvironment{insideverse}{%
\setcounter{saveverselinecounter}{\number\value{poemline}}%
\let\thepoemline\relax%
% Style commands % Change at will
\bfseries\color{red}%
}{%
\setcounter{poemline}{\number\value{saveverselinecounter}}
}

\begin{document}

\verselinenumbersleft
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-2em}
\poemlines{1}

\begin{verse}
To see a World in a Grain of Sand\\
And a Heaven in a Wild Flower,\\!
\begin{insideverse}%
<prose>AND here some prose, which shouldn't be enumerated and also should be styled differently</prose>\\!
\end{insideverse}%
Hold Infinity in the palm of your hand\\
And Eternity in an hour.\\!
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit: Improved version with some control of the `insideverse` environment**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xkeyval}


\makeatletter
\newcounter{saveverselinecounter}[verse@envctr]
\makeatother


\providecommand{\ProvideBool}[2][false]{%
\providebool{#2}%
\setbool{#2}{#1}
\long\csgdef{Enable#2}{%
\booltrue{#2}%
}%
\long\csgdef{Disable#2}{%
\boolfalse{#2}%
}%
}%

\ProvideBool{InsideVerseCentered}%

\makeatletter
\define@boolkey[KV]{InsideVerseKeys}{center}[false]{%
\ifKV@InsideVerseKeys@center%
\EnableInsideVerseCentered%
\else%
\typeout{Nope, disabled!}
\DisableInsideVerseCentered%
\fi%
}%

\define@key{InsideVerseKeys}{topskip}[\baselineskip]{%
\def\KVInsideVerseKeysTopSkip{#1}%
}%

\define@key{InsideVerseKeys}{bottomskip}[\baselineskip]{%
\def\KVInsideVerseKeysBottomSkip{#1}%
}%

\makeatletter



\newenvironment{insideverse}[1][]{%
\setkeys{InsideVerseKeys}{#1}%
\setcounter{saveverselinecounter}{\number\value{poemline}}%
\let\thepoemline\relax%
% Style commands % Change at will
\vspace{\KVInsideVerseKeysTopSkip}%
\bfseries\color{red}%
\ifbool{InsideVerseCentered}{%
\centering%
}{%
\relax%
}%
}{%

\setcounter{poemline}{\number\value{saveverselinecounter}}%
\DisableInsideVerseCentered%
\vspace{\KVInsideVerseKeysBottomSkip}%
}%



\AtBeginDocument{%
\EnableInsideVerseCentered%
}%

\presetkeys{InsideVerseKeys}{center=false,%
                             topskip=0.1\baselineskip,%
                             bottomskip=0.1\baselineskip%
                           }{}%

\begin{document}

\verselinenumbersleft
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-2em}
\poemlines{1}

\begin{verse}
To see a World in a Grain of Sand\\
And a Heaven in a Wild Flower,\\!
\begin{insideverse}[center=true]%
AND here some prose, which shouldn't be enumerated and also should be styled differently%</prose>
\end{insideverse}%
Hold Infinity in the palm of your hand\\
And Eternity in an hour.\\!
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}[1em]
To see a World in a Grain of Sand\\
And a Heaven in a Wild Flower,\\!
\begin{insideverse}[center=false]%
AND here some prose, which shouldn't be enumerated and also should be styled differently%</prose>
\end{insideverse}%
Hold Infinity in the palm of your hand\\
And Eternity in an hour.\\!
\end{verse}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant! But why the inverse text is centered?

Comment: Good question. I believe that the outer verse environment is responsible for that. I will check later on.

Comment: Thanks, btw. I tried to use your example to create a centered inverse environment. Yet line numbers are not aligned with the number of the parent verse `\newenvironment{insideverseCenter}{%
  \setcounter{saveverselinecounter}{\number\value{poemline}}%
  \begin{center}%
    \begin{verse}%
      \setcounter{poemline}{\number\value{saveverselinecounter}}%
    }{%
      \setcounter{saveverselinecounter}{\number\value{poemline}}%
    \end{verse}%
  \end{center}%
  \setcounter{poemline}{\number\value{saveverselinecounter}}%
}`

Comment: @Francesco: I am not sure what you mean? Should the several lines of non-prose content be centered now?

Comment: Nope, just looking for the mechanism to control it. I want to be able to vary within the verse from default to -> prose to -> -> verse centered -> back to default.

Comment: @Francesco: Unfortunately the `verse` environment is rather strict in its alignment, as far as I understood the documentation. I fear, there is not much control of that.